# Why wont .fillStyle update my canvas background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, module, html5-canvas

I am creating a Canvas class with static methods that draw a canvas to a document and change the background color of the canvas.

Adding the canvas to the body is working fine, however the background color is not changing.

I can change the `fillStyle` property using `canvas.context.fillStyle = "#123456"` and logging `canvas.context.fillStyle` which outputs `#123456`.

But when I `log` the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` the `fillStyle` property is not changed.

See console output below.

[image: Screenshot of Console Output]

See the below code

```
export default class Canvas{

    static canvas = null;
    static context = null;
    static backgroundColor = '#0000ff';

    static drawCanvas(){
        Canvas.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        Canvas.context = Canvas.canvas.getContext('2d');
        Canvas.setBackgroundColor(Canvas.backgroundColor);
        document.body.append(Canvas.canvas);
    }


    static setBackgroundColor(bgColor){
        Canvas.backgroundColor = bgColor;

        if (Canvas.context != null) {
            Canvas.context.fillStyle = Canvas.backgroundColor;
            Canvas.context.fillRect(0,0, Canvas.canvas.width, Canvas.canvas.height);

            // See screenshot for console output
            console.log(Canvas.context.fillStyle) // Outputs: #0000ff
            console.log(Canvas.context) // fillstyle outputs: #000000
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of points that may be worth mentioning:

1. The width and height are set in other methods (not shown)
2. I can adjust the border and background color in CSS (but I want to do this in JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to set the background color AFTER I append the canvas.

See below

```
    static drawCanvas(){
        Canvas.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        Canvas.context = Canvas.canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Append Canvas before setting background
        document.body.append(Canvas.canvas);
        Canvas.setBackgroundColor(Canvas.backgroundColor);
    }
```